# Getting “Server unexpectedly closed network connection”

Tags: ubuntu, putty

I created VM by using Jclouds API and by giving the public address in putty login into the VM. I tried to install GUI in VM by giving the below command

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

It is installed but, while rebooting the Ubuntu server I am losing internet connection getting message like below:

```
sudo reboot

Server unexpectedly closed network connection
```

Then the server won't respond.

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck 'Attempt GSSAPI authentication (SSH-2 only)' in Putty:
Category - Connection - SSH - Auth - GSSAPI

In my case it seems to be GSSAPI is incompatible to a Ubuntu host that uses Beyond trust (formerly: likewise open).

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is very simple: When the remote system (Ubuntu) reboots as you commanded it, it will evidently close all programs and connections and reboot... closes the channel too over which putty is communicating - this is why you get the error message Server unexpectedly closed network connection.

Although it says unexpectedly you should have been expecting it when you command it to reboot.

To continue whatever you want with it you have to wait until it starts up then connect to it again.